# Generating 64-byte public key for DH key exchange using Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, .net, diffie-hellman

I need to generate a key pair for Diffie-Hellman key exchange using the `secp256r1` curve using Bouncy Castle in C#. The public key should be 64 bytes (I'm not sure which format this is (compressed?), but I can find out).

I have the following code, but the lack of Bouncy Castle documentation has me lost.

```
X9ECParameters ecParams = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256r1");
var spec = new ECDomainParameters(ecParams.Curve, ecParams.G, ecParams.N, ecParams.H, ecParams.GetSeed());
var keyGenParams = new ECKeyGenerationParameters(spec, new SecureRandom());

var keyGen = new ECKeyPairGenerator("ECDH");
keyGen.Init(keyGenParams);
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = keyGen.GenerateKeyPair();
var pubKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(keyPair.Public);

// pubKeyInfo.GetDerEncoded()
// pubKeyInfo.GetEncoded()
// pubKeyInfo.PublicKey
// pubKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object()
```

From here, I have access to a lot of different export formats (seen above), but most values end up being 335 bytes long. `pubKeyInfo.PublicKeyData.GetBytes()` gives 65 bytes, but I'm not sure why.

I must have some basic misunderstanding here. What am I missing?

If it helps, another client uses the [`uECC_make_key` function](https://github.com/kmackay/micro-ecc/blob/master/uECC.c#L981) to generate the key pair.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the data  is provided by `pubKeyInfo.PublicKeyData.GetBytes()`. It's 65 bytes long because it has a prefix `0x04` byte indicating that the remaining 64 bytes describe the public key in uncompressed format (vs. `0x02` indicating compressed format).

See [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=42384.0) for some discussion.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. From the link, the relevant information is "SEC defines three types: 0x00 = point at infinity, 0x02 and 0x03 = compressed, 0x04 = uncompressed" That prefix defines the public key format .